# Linux Mint Xfce. Map Alt-e to Ctrl-Tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

I have Linux Mint, Xfce.

I want to change tabs in Firefox by pressing Alt-e, rather than by pressing Ctrl-Tab, as is default.

I have been googling this quite a bit, but to no avail.

How do I remap those keys in the ff browser?

Comment: You could try doing it via Firefox AutoConfig, see the `js` answers [here](https://superuser.com/q/1271147)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Firefox extension [shortkeys](https://github.com/crittermike/shortkeys). [Add-on here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/).

Go to the preferences:

```
Shortcut      Label              Behavior
ctrl+e        custom             Next tab
```

In the Behavior case, scroll down then select "Next tab". Restart your browser.

Comment: Thats one way. Mozilla does give the following warning though: "This add-on is not actively monitored for security by Mozilla. Make sure you trust it before installing.". Keyboard input is the last thing on earth that should be handed over to an unmonitored 3rd party. So its barely an option.

Comment: @john-jones Over 99% of browser extensions are unmonitored.  Mozilla currently monitors just 100 of them (out of over 37500, as of this post).  The source code for many extensions is short enough that it doesn't take much time to review the code oneself.  Be sure to not set extensions to auto-update so you can review any upstream changes yourself.  Or create and sign your own `.xpi` files to prevent auto-update.